# MacBook Pro (6,2 - Mid 2010) Crashes During Graphics Acceleration

Tags: macbook-pro, snow-leopard, audio, graphics, crash

Ever since upgrading to 10.6.5 my MacBook pro seems to crash when graphic acceleration. The screen will go black and if audio is playing it will start to skip like a broken record.

This occurs when using the following apps:

- Transmit
- Sparrow Mail
- Pixelmator

and this css3 demo:

- http://lab.simurai.com/ui/zen-player/

Anyone else experiencing similar issues?

Hardware is stock and diagnostics are reporting everything is ok.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like a problem happening when the computer switches to the high-performance (discrete) chip–something in that transition is failing. Open Console from the Utilities folder, and find kernel.log.  See if there are any interesting lines at the time the crash happens.  Probably a few lines with "NVDA" in them.

If you open System Preferences and then Energy Saver, you can adjust the graphics mode - try setting it to high-performance (discrete) all the time.  Either the system will freeze right then, or you can attempt the same tests.  If you still see trouble, it's time to talk to Apple.